# FileAttachment must have an account

Tags: python, email, email-attachments

I'm using Python 2.7 (new in python) and I try to save attachments from e-mails (using exchangelib), here it works very well:

```
for attachment in item.attachments:
        if isinstance(attachment, FileAttachment):
            local_path = os.path.join(filepath, attachment.name)
            with open(local_path, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(attachment.content)
```

my problem is when I try to save attachments from a mail that a mail item was added to it (attach to it), and the mail that added includes a file.

```
elif isinstance(attachment, ItemAttachment):
            if isinstance(attachment.item, Message):
                os.makedirs(filepath+"attachedMail")
                attachedmailpath=filepath+"attachedMail/"
                new_item=attachment.item
                for attachment in new_item.attachments:
                    if isinstance(attachment, FileAttachment):
                        local_path=os.path.join(attachedmailpath,attachment.name)
                        with open(local_path, 'wb') as f:
                            f.write(attachment.content)
```

when I run this code it creates the file with the name of it, but it doesn't write in it, the problem is in **f.write(attachment.content)**

the error that appears is:

```
raise ValueError('%s must have an account' % self.__class__.__name__)
ValueError: FileAttachment must have an account
```

sorry for my English and Thanks!!!

Comment: Please file a bug for this at https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/issues It should be possible to get attachments from an email that was itself added as an attachment.

Answer (score 0):

It is a known bug: https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/issues/210

The workaround is to manually assign the root email as parent_item to each enclosed message.  The following code goes into each attachment recursively, implementing the workaround.

```
...
for MailItem in FilteredMail:
   ReadAttachments(MailItem, MailItem)

def ReadAttachments(MailItem, RootParent)
    for Attachment in MailItem.attachments
        Attachment.parent_item = RootParent
        if hasattr(Attachment, 'item'):    #attachment is a message (exchange object)
            ReadAttachments(Atachment.item, RootParent)
        else:     #attachment is a regular file (e.g. DOC, PDF)
            print Attachment.name + ':' + Attachment.size
            <do whatever with Attachment.content>
```